# Recreate database when running ASP.NET Core Web API on another server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project that is an ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework Core.

A few time ago I created the database using code-first approach with the necessary migrations.

Now I want run the project in other machine and I get the error when I try for example an post to one endpoint:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.

However I think the problem (and I checked with ssms) is that the database doesn't exist.

My connection string, in DbContext is:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
```

What is the best way to recreate the database on this machine?

Thanks

Comment: I only needed execute the command `update-database -context APIAppDbContext`. I added a context since I have a context for the Entities and another one for the Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
;Database=MyDatabase
```

From the connection string.

Then you can create the dtaabase

```
CREATE DaTABASE MyDatabase
```

After the command has run

```
 USE MyDatabase
```

so that you can create tables and run sql commands on it.

This will wrk on any database.

You should check prior to the creation if the database exists, bu that is highly depending on the rdms that you are using

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want execute any sql commands. I want that my API now uses sql local instance, without create the database manually.

Comment: you need to have a database, when you use it in your connection string, that is why i answered it as it is the only way i know of